# Query With Multiple Subqueries Efficiency?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data that looks like this:

```
State   Sex
----    ---
GA      M
GA      M
GA      F
GA      F
GA      F
NY      M
NY      M
NY      M
NY      M
NY      F
NY      F
NY      F
NY      F
NY      F
```

I want the result to be:

1. one row per state
2. col1 State
3. col2 count of Males
4. col3 count of Females
5. col4 total count by state
6. col 5 percent Male by state

The query I am using is:

```
select t.state State, 
M.count Male, 
F.count Female, 
count(t.state) Total,
CONCAT(ROUND(CAST(M.count as float)/CAST(count(t.state) as float)*100, 2), '%') as calc
from MyTable t
join
(
  select state, count(sex) as count 
  from MyTable where sex ='M' 
  group by state) M 
  on t.state = M.state 
join (
  select state, count(sex) as count 
  from MyTable where sex ='F' 
  group by state) F 
  ON M.state = F.state
  group by t.state, m.count, F.count;
```

The above query works but I am wondering if I did this in the most effecent way.
This was done using SQLServer but I think this should be the same for all RDBMS.
The link is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7a969/87

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.state, 
       sum(case when sex = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as males,
       sum(case when sex = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as females,
       count(*) as total,
       avg(case when sex = 'M' then 1.0 else 0 end) as male_ratio
from MyTable t
group by t.state;
```

I would expect this to be the fastest method in just about any database.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7a969/93) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the number of females by subtracting the number of males from the total count per state. This way, only a single `join` is required:

```
with r as (select t.state s, count(*) c from testtable t group by t.state)
select r1.s, t1.m males, r1.c - t1.m females, r1.c total, 100*(t1.m/r1.c) m_percent 
from r r1 
join (select t.state s, t.sex, count(*) m from testtable t group by t.state, t.sex) t1 on r1.s = t1.s where t1.sex = "M";
```

Output:

| state | males | females | total | m_percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GA | 2 | 3 | 5 | 40.0000 |
| NY | 4 | 5 | 9 | 44.4444 |

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=11a2586dde92469ba9c0e2e26459a1978).

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to separate the data out into the tables for *Male* and *Female*.
From a performance point of view, it might help improve performance if the sub-queries were able to make optimal use of indexes, but in reality the chances are low that you would be agregating over only indexed values.

For this simple query you could use simple *CASE* expressions inline to express the `Male`/`Female` columns as `BIT` values, then we can SUM those values in a single aggregation, however that would require you to define the *CASE* for `Male` twice, so you could use it in the `Male` column and the *% Male*.

Instead of inline *CASE* we can use *CROSS APPLY* as a way to resolve calculations against each row **once**, and allow you to reference the result:

```
SELECT t.state State, 
SUM(Calcs.IsMale) Male, 
SUM(Calcs.IsFemale) Female, 
COUNT(1) Total,
CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(Calcs.IsMale)/CAST(COUNT(1) as float)*100, 2), '%') as Calc
FROM MyTable t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 
     CASE Sex WHEN 'M' THEN 1 END as [IsMale]
    ,CASE Sex WHEN 'F' THEN 1 END as [IsFemale]
) as calcs
GROUP BY [State]
```

Is this any more efficient though? In general it should be, this execution plan is much simpler than joining multiple aggregated sets, but its hard to say without a much larger dataset to test it against.

Either way, I would expect this simple CROSS apply version to win as we only have to process the resultset once.

When running the original and the CROSS APPLY on the given dataset and look at the actual execution plans, SQL Sever reports the CROSS APPLY query to be 25% of the relative cost for the batch:

*I apologize in advance for posting this as an image, not really sure if there is a better way to have this discussion*

[image: Execution Plans, OP Nested Join vs Cross Apply]

> This execution plan reports that the Original Query is 3 times the cost of the CROSS APPLY version, probably due to the 3 *table scans* in the first query, compared to the single *table scan* in the CROSS APPLY version.

Comment: Note that `cross apply` is non-standard SQL (and the question isn't tagged with a specific DBMS). In standard SQL that would have to be a `cross join lateral`